# In bootstrap datepicker change month event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have a booking availability checking section on my website. I used `bootstrap datepicker`.

When page loads first time, I am fetching some dates using jquery ajax & php from database to disable dates on datepicker calendar. So, I used `setDatesDisabled`. On first loads of datepicker it is works fine.

When I change month I am getting json response but dates are not disabled on datepicker. I have tried with `changeMonth` event but not working. Please help me to solve this issue

**Json response**

`disableDates:["13.01.2018", "20.01.2018", "27.01.2018"]`

```
$("#dateFrom").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                format: 'dd.mm.yy',
                startDate: new Date()
            }).on('show', function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/cabinowner/bookings/availability',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    type: 'POST'
                })
                    .done(function( response ) {
                        $("#dateFrom").datepicker('setDatesDisabled', response.disableDates);
                    })
                    .fail(function(response, jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                    });
            });

            $("#dateFrom").datepicker().on('changeMonth', function(e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/cabinowner/bookings/availability',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: { date : moment(e.date).format('YY-MM-DD') }
                })
                    .done(function( response ) {
                        // here response is getting but next month is not showing
                        $("#dateFrom").datepicker('setDatesDisabled', response.disableDates);
                    })
                    .fail(function(response, jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                    });
            });

            $("#dateFrom").datepicker().on('changeDate', function(e) {
                var temp   = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                var start  = new Date(temp);
                start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1); // Here date is setting greater than start date

                var end    = new Date(start);
                end.setDate(end.getDate() + 60);

                $("#dateTo").datepicker({
                    autoclose: true,
                    format: 'dd.mm.yy',
                    startDate: start,
                    endDate: end
                });
            });
```

Comment: If you accepted the answer and it helped you the award the bounty to @Grin. It is ending in 1 hour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Next month is not showing because `setDatesDisabled` changes month back.
There is a [demo](https://codepen.io/catthr/pen/VymzRx) with timeout to see it in action.

It happens because at the end the `viewDate` property is updated and it is set to  [`startDate` option or default value (today)](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js#L781). 
 On datepicker rerender - it shows the current `viewDate` thus changes month back.

You can try to disable [`updateViewDate`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#updateviewdate) option when datepicker is initialized.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/catthr/pen/LebBLP)

```
var dp = $('input').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
                startDate: new Date(),
                updateViewDate: false
            });    

dp.on('changeMonth', function (e) {    
    dp.datepicker('setDatesDisabled', ["13.01.2018", "20.01.2018", "27.01.2018"]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the reference wrong here, you are adding 3 different datepickers on the same element. This should work :

```
var datePicker = $("#dateFrom").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    format: 'dd.mm.yy',
    startDate: new Date()
});
datePicker.on('show', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cabinowner/bookings/availability',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST'
    })
        .done(function (response) {
            datePicker.setDatesDisabled(response.disableDates);
        })
        .fail(function (response, jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        });
});

datePicker.on('changeMonth', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/cabinowner/bookings/availability',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {date: moment(e.date).format('YY-MM-DD')}
    })
        .done(function (response) {
            // here response is getting but next month is not showing
            datePicker.setDatesDisabled(response.disableDates);
        })
        .fail(function (response, jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        });
});

datePicker.on('changeDate', function (e) {
    var temp = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var start = new Date(temp);
    start.setDate(start.getDate() + 1); // Here date is setting greater than start date

    var end = new Date(start);
    end.setDate(end.getDate() + 60);

    $("#dateTo").datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd.mm.yy',
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end
    });
});
```

Comment: I had tried this code but I am getting error in console `Uncaught TypeError: datePicker.setDatesDisabled is not a function`

Comment: I think it be an async issue. May be something need before callback. But I don't know how to handle this. I am using package `http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/`

Answer (score 1):

- you are trying to create multiple datapicker which must be only 1.
- you can save datepicker init with var. and use it if you want access it later
- datepicker on show will recalled on startup, change month, change year etc (every time table displayed). so we need to set a variable to only call ajax on datepicker startup only. in here, i name it `opened`

try this

```js
 $(function(){
  var opened = false;
  var dp = $('.datepicker').datepicker({
   autoclose: true,
   todayHighlight: true,
   format: 'dd.mm.yy',
   startDate: new Date(),
  }).on('show', function(){
   if(!opened){
    $.ajax({
     url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5a4005be0401cf6341fb830b', //["28.12.2017","20.01.2018","27.01.2018"]
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'get',
     success: function(d){
      opened = true;
      dp.datepicker('setDatesDisabled', d);
     },
     error: function(){
      alert('error');
     }
    });
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"/> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" />

<style>
        .datepicker-dropdown table td.disabled, .datepicker-dropdown table td.disabled:hover {
            background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.13) !important;
            color: red !important;
            cursor: not-allowed !important;
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" class="datepicker">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```